# Intellisense and Debugging javascript в visual studio 2012

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, intellisense, durandal

Начал изучать Durandal. Ну так как работаю давно в Visual Studio, я не хочу переходить на другой редактор. В изучении Durandal (HTML, CSS, JQuery, JavaScript, Knockout, bootstrap) проблем нет. По не многу, по не многу и все становиться логично. Но есть одна проблема, которая так бесит и нервирует что сил нет. Я меня толком не работает **Intellisense** в проекте. Например, подключил библиотеки Knockout и jquery  и Intellisense  не работает. Не все методы видны, так же когда привяжу html страницу к javascript файлу, то в HTML невидно никаких функций JS. Так же проблема с knockout. Даже Data-bind неработает толком.
Я вообще чеснок говоря растерян и не знаю как работать. Это катастрофично неудобно.Так же проблема в Дебаге кода. Как вообще JavaScript программисты работают?? Вот в C# все просто. Дебагер на отличном уровне, все работает все знаешь и видишь. Короче говоря друзья, помогите. Объясните мне тупому,  как работать с Debug'ром и как подсвечивать методы следующих технологий, которые присутствуют в Durandal:

1. HTML, CSS (Более менее нормальный Intellisense установил WebEssentials)
2. jQuery,JavaScript,**Knockout** - с этим вообще проблемы. Я ничего не понимаю в том, как сделать подсветку этой технологии.
3. Друзья, кто работает с данными технологиями, **подскажите дополнения для студии, ваши методы работы и направите в нужную сторону.**

Пример:Нет переменной, которую создал в HTML
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image]

Реально ли настроить [intellisense](/questions/tagged/intellisense) так как я хотел бы. Если нет. то расскажите ***оптимальный вариант.***

Comment: TagOverflow )))

Comment: Исправил теги .

Comment: У вас списках планет Плутон, это же неправильно! Настроить — нереально. Тому есть разные причины, в первую очередь сам характер JavaScript (отсутствие модулей). В студии есть всякие костыли (самый мощный — VS2015), которые это "лечат", но проще привыкнуть обходится без него. И ещё ваш `computed` c вопросиком не будет работать, т.к. `this` будет неправильный. Его надо передавать вторым аргументом, чтобы было так как вы хотите (это я к тому что отсутствие интеллисенса это меньшая из бед).

Comment: Хех, я так и понял. Стараюсь уже обходиться без него. Пока с трудностью получается, не понимаю как debug делать. Я уже понял что нужно привыкать  к тому что есть.

Comment: @PawełGroński дебаг - в браузере, там всё очень даже неплохо, лучше всего подходит Chrome там лучший отладчик на мой взгляд.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую.